# gRPC-web cannot connect to server (proxy configuration problem)

Tags: docker, proxy, envoyproxy, grpc-web

I am trying to create a grpc-web client to connect to my grpc server. I already have my grpc server written in C++ and it works well with C# client, everything is okay and tested. Right now I am trying to create a js client to connect to my service. 
So what I would expect is to return a simple "hello" back to me but what I get is: "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".

I have fallowed this tutorial: [hello world](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/tree/master/net/grpc/gateway/examples/helloworld) and also tried that one: [fron proxy from grpc-web](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/tree/master/examples/front-proxy)

I have generated proto files succesfuly. 
my client looks like that:

```
const {HelloRequest, HelloResponse} = require('./definitions_pb.js');
const {GreeterClient} = require('./definitions_grpc_web_pb.js');

var echoService = new GreeterClient('http://192.168.88.150:8080');

var request = new HelloRequest();
request.setName('Mark');

echoService.sayHello(request, {}, function(err, response) {
  // ...
});
```

what I am confused about is the proxy that I have to run in docker, so I suspect it is messed up. My envoy.yaml file looks like that:

```
admin:
  access_log_path: /tmp/admin_access.log
  address:
    socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 9091 }

static_resources:
  listeners:
  - name: listener_0
    address:
      socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 8080 }
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
        config:
          codec_type: auto
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: local_service
              domains: ["*"]
              routes:
              - match: { prefix: "/" }
                route:
                  cluster: greeter_service
                  max_grpc_timeout: 0s
              cors:
                allow_origin:
                - "*"
                allow_methods: GET, PUT, DELETE, POST, OPTIONS
                allow_headers: keep-alive,user-agent,cache-control,content-type,content-transfer-encoding,custom-header-1,x-accept-content-transfer-encoding,x-accept-response-streaming,x-user-agent,x-grpc-web,grpc-timeout
                max_age: "1728000"
                expose_headers: custom-header-1,grpc-status,grpc-message
                enabled: true
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.grpc_web
          - name: envoy.cors
          - name: envoy.router
  clusters:
  - name: greeter_service
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    type: logical_dns
    http2_protocol_options: {}
    lb_policy: round_robin
    hosts: [{ socket_address: { address: 192.168.88.150, port_value: 50051 }}]
```

and Docker file:

```
 FROM envoyproxy/envoy:latest
COPY ./envoy.yaml /etc/envoy/envoy.yaml
CMD /usr/local/bin/envoy -c /etc/envoy/envoy.yaml
```

I use " `npx webpack client.js` " to create main.js.

To start envoy proxy I do as they say in the tutorial:

```
>> docker build -t envoy -f ./Dockerfile .
>> docker run -d -p 8080:8080 envoy
```

and after starting my server, running that docker stuff and starting my web:

```
py -m http.server 8081
```

I get that error I have mentioned at the start. I was thinking of CORS blocking but it is enabled in the envoy file. I would really appreaciate any help.

@@Edit

So I have also tried that [envoy-front](https://www.learnenvoy.io/articles/on-your-laptop.html) and I have problems with `curl` instruction in that example. Mainly I get: `Invoke-WebRequest : Unable to connect to the remote server`. I susperct it has to do with my docker machine but I do not know what. Oh and also I am using Docker-Toolbox and not Docker for Windows because mym system does not support Docker for Windows.

Comment: Did you find any solution about it with a description?